# What is 'identifying restricted Boltzmann machine'?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, machine-learning, geometric-topology, tropical-geometry

Currently, I am going through [Geometry of the Restricted Boltzmann Machine](https://arxiv.org/abs/0908.4425) by Cueto et al.

In this paper (in the abstract, multiple places in Section 1, etc.), the authors use the concept of the identification of restricted Boltzmann machine.

What does 'identification' mean in this context? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"**Identifiability**" means you can find a unique solution that generates your observations. Unidentifiable models have multiple solutions that are equivalent.

Comment: Is there any problem with having multiple solutions? If not, we do we need to determine the identifiability?

Comment: solutions to non-identifiable problems are harder to interpret for one...

Comment: could you please elaborate?  What do you mean by interpretation?